# Understanding a small UML representation of interfaces, class and inheritance?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface, uml

I need to implement this UML in code. Can someone help me understand 2 questions about this UML representation? This is for a programming class in Java.

[image]

The exercise states:

The StringFilter is the class where clients may add several specific word filters, represented by the interface Filter.

The StringFilter does not depend on any specific filter. As an example, the ContainsWord filter is a standard filter provided by the library, while ContainsText and LengthBelow are developed by the client.

I'm having trouble understanding the relationships in the UML.

--

1st Question:

From my understanding, StringFilter is a class. And StringFilter, implements the interface Filter. Is this true? If in the code, I were to define **StringFilter implements Filter**, would it be correct?

--

2nd Question:

ContainsWord is a class, and implements the accept() method, defined in the interface Filter. Is this true? And should **ContainsWord implement Filter**?

--

I'm having trouble understanding what implements what exactly. Relationships from **ContainsWord** to the interface **Filter** and **StringFilter** to the interface **Filter**, are somewhat confusing to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `StringFilter` does not implement `Filter`. `StringFilter` uses instances of `Filter` to do its job (v.g., the `addFilter` method). The "implements" (in UML speech I think it is "realizes") line is the dashed one.

2) That is exactly what the diagram represents. `ContainsWord` is a implementation (UML -> realization) of `Filter` and so must implement `accept`.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  In addition, in case it's any help to you: the arrow from StringFilter to Filter, with a diamond at the StringFilter end, indicates that StringFilter 'contains' Filter; the asterisk on the Filter end of that line indicates that it contains more than one.  So anything that has the dashed line with open arrowhead going to Filter can be a parameter to the addFilter() method of StringFilter.

Comment: @SJuan76 To be more precise. There are 6 dashed lines in the diagram, whereas only 3 of them represents realization relationship. The key point is the hollow triangle end of the line/arrow.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. `StringFilter` uses the Filter instance to get the task done. Therefore the relationship between `Filter` and `StringFilter` is realization. The arrow side instance is used by the diamond side class. For example,

   Class StringFilter{ Filter filter ;...}

2.Yes. `ContainsWord` class will implement the `Filter` interface and provide the implementation of accept method.Same for `ContainsText` and `LengthBelow` classes